# Snowflake: How to connect to snowflake using .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am working on a new Project and requirement of the project is to design an API endpoint that connects with Snowflake using .NET Core

As I am new to the Snowflake, I referred to the sample application provided by Microsoft in GitHub [Link](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/). As per the link, Snowflake is supported only in VS2017 and .NET Framework version. Will t supports in .NET Core as well?

I am trying to connect to Snowflake using HttpClient as below:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var t = await client.GetAsync("https://mza44345.snowflakecomputing.com");
```

It was throwing status code:403 Forbidden.

What NuGet packages do I need to install in order to connect to Snowflake using .NET Core?

Please help with an easy way to connect to Snowflake using .NET Core?
If possible any Sample application/ sample code to connect with snowflake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/snowflake-with-c-sharp-net-core/ 

It has step by step guide for .net core. 
in the post they are using the connection string, so make sure you have connection string. 
hope this helps.

**Edit 1**
the [one](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net) you are using, it supports .net standard and all the .net core application supports .net standard.

Comment: Hi Manish! I want to connect to Snowflake using EF Core and perform CRUD operations, If so, can you suggest me the NugetPackages

Answer (score 0):

The error can also be due to the incorrect/typo in URL address. Can you please check if it correct?

Comment: I have given my snowflake URL.